# Slideshow screensaver in Win-7 vs. XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, photos, screensaver

Since I skipped Vista, this may be an old question, I don't know.

In XP, the built-in SlideShow (Photos) screensaver would randomly rotate among images not just in the directory specified in the settings, but also in any sub-directories (and on down) of that directory.  When I use the Photos screensaver in Win-7, it seems to use only images in the directory I specify, ignoring the rest of the tree below that.

Is there a way to get the XP behavior?  Alternatively, is there some other public domain/open source Screen Saver with that or similar behavior that I can install?

Comment: Works fine for me, the Win7 Photos screensaver picks the images in the specified directory AND the sub-directories.

Comment: Hmm.  It looks like you're right.  One of my machines it fired right up.  The other one stubbornly insisted on displaying the same 5 pictures over and over. But I removed those from the root directory that the screensaver was pointed to, so there were only directories underneath it, and it started displaying everything.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question right now.

Answer (score 3):

If you install [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) (which is free); it comes with an added screensaver, which has a variety of options. One of which is to choose what folders the pictures come from along with a few other settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in slideshows as screensavers or standalone applications, I would recommend [Irfanview](http://irfanview.com). I've been using it for about 6 years and have always been happier with it as a fast image viewer and slideshow generator than the apps included with Windows.

It does not give you options for fancy transitions or animation, but will let you save a particular slideshow as a screen saver (scr) or executable file (exe).

Comment: Google also has a slideshow screensaver that is more popular and has more features than Windows 7 slideshow screensaver.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out [PhotoJoy](http://www.photojoy.com/index.aspx)...free, numerous screensavers, and some very nice ones that work with your photos collection...highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to copy the XP slide-show screen-saver from a XP driven PC - C:/Windows/System32/ to the same place in the Windows 7.

It's the file - ssmypics.scr - to copy.

This is a nice and stable screen-saver it works nicely in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

[gPhotoShow Free](http://www.gphotoshow.com/gpshow_free.htm) is a screensaver that will search sub folders.